# What exactly is a MIME type

Tags: manifest, mime-types, mime, html5-appcache

I've researched but all I can find is that the manifest file should have the correct MIME type & that's text/cache-manifest. I have no idea ***what*** a MIME type is.

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type?

Comment: "closed as too broad by Dour High Arch, Stilly.stack, Robert P., CJM, Nicolas Bachschmidt Feb 22 at 0:49"   I already got my answer, was doing that really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in WikiPedia:

> An Internet media type is a standard identifier used on the Internet
>   to indicate the type of data that a file contains. Common uses include
>   the following:
>
> email clients use them to identify attachment files,
>   web browsers use them to determine how to display or output files that are not in HTML format,
>   search engines use them to classify data files on the web.
>
> A media type is composed of a type, a subtype, and zero or more
>   optional parameters. As an example, an HTML file might be designated
>   text/html; charset=UTF-8. In this example text is the type, html is
>   the subtype, and charset=UTF-8 is an optional parameter indicating the
>   character encoding.
>
> IANA manages the official registry of media types.
>
> The identifiers were originally defined in RFC 2046, and were called
>   MIME types because they referred to the non-ASCII parts of email
>   messages that were composed using the MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail
>   Extensions) specification. They are also sometimes referred to as
>   Content-types.
>
> Their use has expanded from email sent through SMTP, to other
>   protocols such as HTTP, RTP and SIP.

Answer (score 1):

MIME types have this name because of their original purpose. According to Wikipedia:

> Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) is an Internet standard
>   that extends the format of email to support: Text in character sets
>   other than ASCII, Non-text attachments, Message bodies with multiple
>   parts, Header information in non-ASCII character sets.
>
> Although MIME was designed mainly for SMTP protocol, its use today has
>   grown beyond describing the content of email and now often includes
>   describe content type in general, including for the web (see Internet
>   media type) and as a storage for rich content in some commercial
>   products (e.g., IBM Lotus Domino and IBM Lotus Quickr).
>
> Virtually all human-writt"en Internet email and a fairly large
>   proportion of automated email is transmitted via SMTP in MIME format.
>   Internet email is so closely associated with the SMTP and MIME
>   standards that it is sometimes called SMTP/MIME email.[1] The content
>   types defined by MIME standards are also of importance outside of
>   email, such as in communication protocols like HTTP for the World Wide
>   Web. HTTP requires that data be transmitted in the context of
>   email-like messages, although the data most often is not actually
>   email.